# asp.net core API Description with Swagger and Generic BaseController

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

Given `BaseController`

```
public class BaseController<TViewModel> : ControllerBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a <see cref="T:TViewModel"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public IActionResult Details(
        [FromRoute] string id)
    {
        return Ok(new TViewModel());
    }
}
```

and the implementation

```
public class ItemsController : BaseController<ItemViewModel>
```

The following Documentation is generated
[image: resulting api docu]

I would like to see *Returns a Item*

is there a way to resolve the Generics?

Comment: Hi @Marius Steinbach, put aside your current question, from your current approach with `new TViewModel()` will not work directly because generics in C# require the type to have a parameterless constructor to be instantiated in this manner.